# Customize Telerik chart

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-charting

I'm trying to add a functionality to Telerik MVC Q3 chart (I need the chart to show some summary lines, for instance minimum, maximum or average lines). I downloaded the visual studio solution from codeplex, but it's too hard to make any changes because I couldn't find any documentation on this project. I somehow managed to add the server side configuration part, but now I'm really stuck with the javascript part. Could someone advise how can I get the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Telerik does not have an extensive client-side api. What there is can be found in their docs.

- [Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC Manual](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/introduction.html)

  Under Telerik UI Components, there is a section called "Client API and Events" for each component. For example, [Grid Client API and Events](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-client-api-and-events.html).
- [Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC Demos](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/)

  The demos all have a small demo of client-side events. For example, [Grid Client-Side Events](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/clientsideevents).
- Another resource that might be useful on the [ASP.NET Wiki](http://www.aspnetwiki.com/) is an article by John DeVight called "[Telerik MVC : Extending the Client API](http://www.aspnetwiki.com/page%3aextending-the-telerik-mvc-client-api)". Also the [Telerik MVC Series](http://www.aspnetwiki.com/telerik-mvc) might be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I couldn't find any information about the javascript codes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts Daniel, the links you provided were useful, but I still couldn't find something like documentation for the javascript codes, in order to be able to modify them (not to extend via plugins). I think that Telerik simply failed to provide such a documentation (bad practice for open-source project).